# GKE GUI overview showing shutdown pods

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

When looking at the "Workloads" within the GKE GUI, it shows some of the deployments as shutdown even though they are working correctly.

[image: picture 1 - deployments in GUI]

When looking at the Pods of such a "shutdown" deployment, there is lots of shutdown pods but one is running (as expected - there should be just one pod running and the others were shutdown for any reason in the past).

[image: picture 2 - pods within a single "shutdown" deployment]

I get the same result when using `kubectl`. The deployments that are marked "OK" have just a one pod so far so they will become "shutdown" in the future as the pods will be shutdown and restarted.

The question is how to get rid of such pods automatically so that it's not confusing and also to shorten the pods listing via `kubectl` without any additional filtering.

**EDIT:**

There are deployments (picture 1) managing pods, detail of one of the "shutdown" deployments is in picture 2, listing its pods. The deployment is actually working but is marked as "Shutdown" in the GUI.

`kubectl get deploy` is giving me the deployments correctly (some deployments have a single replica, some have 2 replicas, that's OK):

[image]

`kubectl get pods` is giving me something like this (all the listed pods belong to a single deployment but there should be just a single pod - the one that is running):

[image]

The question remains - how to make these pods to disappear?

**EDIT 2:**

I found out there is default `revisionHistoryLimit` set to 10, i.e. there should be 10 past ReplicaSets kept (which seems to be true in the GUI). But even within each (old) ReplicaSet there are multiple pods with the "Shutdown" status. All of this is probably causing the Deployment seems to be in a Shutdown state even though it's working correctly.

Comment: Could you clarify: what do you see with kubectl? What are those "shutdown" pods? Are those jobs that did complete, or pods not managed by a deployment/replicaset/... that did exit and are not meant to be restarted?

Comment: @SYN I updated the question with more details.

Comment: The `revisionHistoryLimit` in your Deployment definition is a limit on ReplicaSets. When you make a change, a new RS is created, and previous copies may or may not be removed. Pods being re-scheduled doesn't enter into consideration here.

Comment: I didn't know Shutdown is an actual Pod status in k8s, my bad => github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/28235. Apparently, this would suggest the pod was evicted. Check those Pods description for further details, may be related to nodes shutting down or restarting (autoscaling, cluster upgrade?). Failed pod objects will be preserved until explicitly deleted or cleaned up by the GC https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-garbage-collection.

Comment: @SYN Yes, I know the reason, the Pods evicted because of the node shutdown (I am using preemptible VMs here so that happens at least once a day).
OK, so it seems that "Shutdown" Pods will not disappear automatically (thanks for the hint) - at least until the "parent" ReplicaSet is removed from the history after reaching the `revisionHistoryLimit`. I can live with that. However, the Deployments marked as Shutdown in the GCP GUI are confusing...

Comment: Hi. Just ran into the very same issue. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: @MartinD No, I couldn't fix it anyhow. However, now it seems that in the GUI it's OK, I don't see shutdown deployments anymore. On the deployment details page I can see shutdown pods in grey now (instead of red). `kubectl` is still listing them...

Comment: @MartinD Well, in the GUI, I can now see grey and also red Shutdown pods. The red ones cause the deployment to be red (shutdown) as well even though it's working correctly. If the deployment covers grey Shutdown pods (no red ones), then the deployment is green (OK). It's really very confusing...

Comment: @MartinGrůber thank you for your answers. In the meanwhile I contacted GKE Support and just received a response saying the issue was indeed in GKE and it should be fixed now. I can confirm that I no longer see failing Deployments in GKE Console (although that may be just a coincidence). Please check on your end - it may be fixed. :)

Comment: @MartinD Yeah, I can confirm that it seems to be fixed now.